# How to condition an expresion to not deliver NaN in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

My expresion i want to condition to not result in NaN is [New Cases] / [Total Cases] becasue in my data mart that allows nulls sometimes de expresion has nothing to go of.

Ive tried building expresions with ISNULL and ? conditions by I havent been able to understand proper syntax for this expresion to not return NaN or devide by 0.

Comment: Please show us your tried code! SSIS conditional mentality is quite different!

Answer (score 0):

You're liking looking for a Derived Column transformation. If the expression you are using is `[New Cases] / [Total Cases]` then you need to guard against Total Cases being zero.

The Ternary Expression can be read as  `(Condition) ? True Case: False Case`

```
([Total Cases] != 0) ? [New Cases] / [Total Cases] : 0.0
```

In English that is: If the total cases is not equal to zero, then use the formula "New Cases divided by Total Cases". Otherwise, use zero point zero. The use of `0.0` is an attempt to help the SSIS Expression language infer data types as both the true and false expression need to yield the same data type.

Also depending on data types, if [Total Cases] is a whole number type (DT_INT16, DT_INT32, DT_INT64) then we're working with integer division in the True case which may or may not be what you want. Integer division truncates the remainder. If that is not the behaviour you want then an expression like this might be needed

```
([Total Cases] != 0) ? [New Cases] / (1.0 * [Total Cases]) : 0.0
```

The multiplication of 1.0 (a floating point number) against the Total Cases is short hand for changing the divisor's data type to ensure float point division is used instead of integer division.